# Eslint rule to validate pascal case on react compoent name (only for .tsx extension)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, pascalcasing

I'm trying to use Eslint to enforce `PascalCase` on my React components. 
I've looked at all the existing plugins/rules I could find, and here are my issues:

I'm using Typescript (.tsx extensions), so react/jsx-pascal-case won't work for me.
For files that are not components, I do want to allow kebab-case, so i'd like to filter out only files with the .tsx extension.

TL;DR - Id like an Eslint rule to enforce PascalCase, but only on files ending with `.tsx`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what I needed was the `eslint-plugin-filenames` plugin and it's `"filenames/match-exported"` rule. This doesn't enforce that the actual component is called using pascal case, but this can be enforced maybe using @wentjun's answer

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) extension for your eslint setup.

Then, you may refer to the [naming-convention](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md) rule, which will allow you to enforce pascal case for your components.

Comment: Thanks @wentjun. I'm not seeing a `filename` option in the allowed selectors. It looks like the rule is looking at code inside files. I'm not looking to enforce the component name, but rather the file name. I might be able to use this in combination with the filenames/match-exported rule..

Comment: @UriKlar Ahh.. I am afraid that rule itself might not be specific enough. Have you managed to figure it out?

Comment: Yes, I used `filenames/match-exported` which makes the filename match the export name. So as long as the component is defined with pascal case, so will the filename